# Windows equivalent find -delete

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, cmd

What is the Windows/DOS equivalent to this Linux command?

`find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete`

I know how to delete all the files but not how to specify an exception (ie: not deleting `__init__.py`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cmd.exe doesn't support wildcards in several levels of a path (PowerShell does) so you've to emulate this somehow.

Cmd line:

```
for /f "delims=" %F in ('Dir /B /S .\*.py ^|findstr /IE "\\migrations\\[^\\]*.py"^|findstr /IEV "\\__init__.py" ') Do @echo del "%F"
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `echo`
In a batch file double the percent signs `%F` => `%%F`

PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem .\*\migrations\*.py -exclude __init__.py | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf`

In this sample tree

```
> tree /F
A:.
└───test
    │   alpha.py
    │   bravo.py
    │
    └───migrations
            alpha.py
            bravo.py
            __init__.py
```

the output will be

```
del "A:\test\migrations\alpha.py"
del "A:\test\migrations\bravo.py"
```

---

```
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei entfernen" für das Ziel "A:\test\migrations\alpha.py".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei entfernen" für das Ziel "A:\test\migrations\bravo.py".
```

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are not possible (as far as I know) in Windows/DOS search, but they are possible in `xcopy /exclude` and `robocopy /X...`. Therefore I'd advise you to copy all but the exceptions to a kind of backup folder, remove all the original ones (including the exceptions) and put everything back.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `for /R` and `if`, something like this:

```
for /r %i in (*.py) do (
  if "%~ni"=="__init__" (
    echo Skipping %i
  ) else (
    echo del "%i"
  )
)
```

Here I've prefixed the `del` command with `echo` so it doesn't actually delete it.  Once it looks like it's doing what you want, then take away that echo.

If you do this in a batch file, you'll need to double up the % signs.

The `for /R` is a recursive for, and in that format will work from the current directory.

The `%~ni` says "give me the filename part only, of %i"

(I'm running Linux at the moment so I can't verify exact behaviour, but you could start with this).

Comment: The restriction of parentfolder `migrations` is missing.